# Pound sign formatting issue in CSV reports

Tags: magento2.4, reports

We have a client running on Magento 2.4 and their store's currency is British Pounds (GBP).

When they export any sales reports from the Reports menu (eg Reports > Sales > Orders) the pound character is shown in Excel with an "a-circumflex" character (Â) before the actual pound sign like this:

```
Â£137.08
```

When I check the format of the generated CSV file it is in UTF-8 format, and if I convert it to ASCII format in a code editor and then save the file this prevents the unwanted characters from being shown in Excel. However, we need a solution to prevent this from happening as we can't expect non-technical users to handle file format conversions.

Can anyone suggest how we can change the format of Magento's generated CSV files to ASCII or else just remove the currency symbol from the file?